# Stock Market Trade Occurrences

Tags: poisson-distribution, count-data, frequency

I am looking at a simple set of data that details the occurrence of a stock market trade for a particular hour of the day. So, based on the data avilable, I have created a grouping for every hour (0-1, 1-2, 2-3, etc...). The only information available other than the exact time that the trade was made (which is what I used to create the grouping) is the date of the trade. I'd like to examine if the time of day plays a significant role in the occurrence of a trade, and then more broadly if the day itself plays a significant role.

Trying to figure out the best way to model this, I have a couple of questions that I'm not sure how to answer:

- Is there a way to use the actual times as a response rather than grouping them together?
- Or is my best bet to use a poisson regression, using the frequencies of hour as my response, and the hour as my predictor?

I'm thinking using actual time as a response can help determine if Day plays a significant role, but poisson is the only way to examine time of day's role. Are there any more models that I am missing, or a better way to handle this?

Comment: If you use hour as numeric input, it becomes difficult to model non linear inside a day. For example the volatility smile effect can bear zero linear dependency on day time. You can try using 23 dummy binary hour variables as input to catch significance of the hour.

Comment: Wouldn't using hour as a factor (possible ordinal factor) take care of this, rather than 23 dummies?

Comment: Hour changes linearly. Trade number does not.